# Yii 1 + bootstrap modal popup issue

Tags: php, yii, bootstrap-modal

When we load cgridview using bootstrap modal popup (remote content) then after reopening popup if we click on paging link then there are multiple requests are occurred how to prevent it?

I have tried using the dynamic id in cgridview and much more but seems the issue is not resolved. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, after digging more and more I got the solution. Basically, the problem was I have a grid on the main page and from that page, there was button to open popup with another grid and in popup when we reopen popup and click on pagination then it was requesting as many times as popup was opened. For e.g. if popup was opened 5 times then there was 5 request are made and 4 was aborted by browser. To stop it I apply below solution.

You just need to create dynamic grid id for that popup grid and pass the same id to ajax request to maintain grid id and cgridview works perfectly.

In your controller put

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['ajax'])) {
            $this->gridId = 'timesheet-report-grids'.rand(1,15000);
        } else if(isset($_REQUEST['ajax']) && $_REQUEST['ajax'] != '') {
            $this->gridId = $_REQUEST['ajax'];
        } else {
            $this->gridId = 'timesheet-report-grids'; // Just to prevent error in any case
        }
```

and use `$this->gridId` in your view file in cgridview widget.